# IIS 7 serves up blank image

Tags: iis-7

I have a folder containing a folder structure with some images. 
If I request an image `mysite.com/folder/subfolder/image.jpg` I get a blank page back.
Fiddler says the content length is 0, but the result is 200.

If i deliberately misspell folder or file name I get 401. So clearly IIS knows something is there.

I am at a loss. Thanks!

Comment: Something in your web configuration instructs IIS to treat .jpg not simply as serving the image but rather create a custom response. I'll leave it to the real admin pros to find the exact cause.

Comment: Hmm, I have the same web app running on the different server with the exact same web.config and the images from the second server show up fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static Content module wasn't installed on this server...